# how can I achieve a similar effect in ConTeXt

Tags: luatex, metapost, context-lmtx

I am completely new to ConTeXt and have just started to experiment with writing metapost directly within ConTeXt. In Latex , I can use the tcolorbox macro package to achieve the effect of output on the left and code on the right, and the output part on the left accounts for 40%, and the code part on the right accounts for 60%,my question is, how can I achieve a similar effect in ConTeXt? [image]

Comment: Just adapt the code (widths of the columns in the table and switch the order of the result and the code) from your previous question on the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enthusiasm